# How to disable 'Unused import'-warnings on Ionic2 / Angular2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, tslint

I know there is an option to disable those 'Unused Import' warnings give by `tslint` when running `ionic serve` or `ionic build`. But I have no idea where to put it. Does anyone know? Thanks

[1] https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-unused-variable/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, that was quick.. Like often. I'm looking for days for a solution, but immediately after I post my question here, I find the solution on my own.

So, for all having the same problems during developing, you can set `no-unused-variable` to `false` in the file `tslint.json`.

But don't forget to enable it again when you go to production.

Answer (score 7):

go into your `tslint.json` press ctrl+F, replace `true` with `false`

Comment: Thx, found it by myself :)

Comment: @SoS ah nice, indeed very quick hahah, I myself disabled all tslint options, haven't had a single error which actually mattered because of it. Matter of preference I guess