# What will happens when I import unused additions in Ionic 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, import, ionic2, ionic3

My question very simple, I want to know what will happens if I imported unused components or variables or any thing else ?

Because as I see in my cmd lines, there's some red lines or marker but there is no visible actions... So should I take care for this case or I'm fine ?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are [`tslint`](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/) warnings.

Importing unused modules and creating unrequired variables leads to bad code. It does not stop your application from running. But **it causes needless loading of modules which can cause performance and maintainability issues**.

It is best to heed these warnings and clean up your imports.

If you wish to disable this warning and not have this code checking, you can check [How to disable 'Unused import'-warnings on Ionic2 / Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40788655/how-to-disable-unused-import-warnings-on-ionic2-angular2) to see how to disable it.

Comment: Yes, sure I will remove these unused imports if I did my work. But I was think there is no actions if I put them

Comment: They are not _errors_. Not sure what actions you were expecting.